# How can I store data for a line of numbers logic?

Tags: javascript

So basically I have this code in a discord bot that'll appear in general-chat, and it says "Guess the correct number from 1-10" and it's a random number each time.

So, what this code is supposed to do, is every time a incorrect number is guessed, it'll update the "line of numbers" to make it slightly obvious what the number is.

Example: They guess numbers 1, 4, 5, and 7.

The embed should look like

`1 _ _ 4 5 _ 7 _ _ _`, but what's happening is that it doesn't save every single guess, so it'll only update the embed with the last guessed number

`_ _ _ _ _ _ 7 _ _ _` ( like this ), so how can I store all of the incorrect guessed answers, to work like how I want it to?

code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/rowexaketi.js

Comment: _"how can I store all of the incorrect guessed answers"_... in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an array with all the guesses that go wrong. Create that array in a scope that is visible for your function, and than you use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if that number was tried before.

Example:

```js
const triedNumbers = [5,9,10]; // Start it as empty array, this is just for testing
const possibleValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    
// Use reduce instead of mapping to transform the array into a string later
const finalString = possibleValues.reduce((accumulated, current) => {
    if(triedNumbers.includes(current)) return `${accumulated}${current}`;
    return `${accumulated}_`;
}, '');

console.log(finalString);
```

[Link to reduce docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

A couple of suggestions: change the variables names of your code, you have multiple indexes: index, index3, index4, which makes really difficult to read and understand how your code is working. Also, if you are creating variables that are not going to be mutated later, [use const instead of let](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, but I'm still not exactly sure how this can solve my issue.
I'm pushing the incorrect guesses to the triedNumbers array, using ``.push``, and the Embed still comes up empty. I'm not completely sure what I'm doing wrong.
Also thanks for the extra suggestions, much appreciated :)
Here's the current code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/lowiqazoze.js

Comment: That's because every time you run your code you are reassigning the value of the array as empty and pushing only the current incorrect answer. You need to create the triedNumbers array in a place that will not be executed every time a number is tried, but in location where it will be called only once

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't even realize where I had been placing the triedNumbers 
(Also for anyone watching this thread that may have help, don't be dumb, and make sure to convert the array into an int)

Comment: You are welcome, but don't call yourself dumb for mistakes. That's the beauty of coding, and the main reason Stackoverflow exists.